# Children of the Gods plot inconsistency?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

In Stargate SG-1's pilot episode *Children of the Gods*, the scene opens with a group of soldiers playing poker in the gate room. These soldiers have some minor banter about how "nobody ever comes down here except us" when one of them raises concern over getting caught.

However, when Jack O'Neill is brought onto the base and taken to see General Hammond, he is in the same office he is always in, just above the gate room, and he seems well settled in.

If in fact "nobody ever comes down here", how come General Hammond's office is in use just a short distance away? Is this a plot error?

Comment: Perhaps they meant that no one ever goes down to the gate room. Hammond's office was a floor or two (not levels) above the gate room, off of the control room.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that all the offices in a bunker complex like that are very similar. If he did have his office moved, likely some airmen would have arranged it exactly as it appeared previously. Would you be able to tell a difference?

Comment: I doubt all of the other offices would have a window looking out into the room overlooking the gate though, which is clearly visible in the episode (as Kawalsky and Feretti get bought in for questioning and O'Neil states "You're questioning my men?")

Comment: I stand corrected. It's been years since I've seen it.

Comment: I saw it as an indeterminate amount of time between the raid and the O'Neill/Hammond scene. Sure, likely to be short, but maybe as much as a few days - enough for what was a mothballed base to get up and running again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's been ages since I've seen it as well, but were the blast doors closed? I.e. the view of the gate from the meeting room near Hammond's office may have been obstructed.

Of course there's always the obvious explanation: Hammond WAS in his current office, and he could see what was going on, but chose to ignore it. Why?

- We've seen on multiple occasions that General Hammond was a big softie, willing to be swayed by whatever crazy hair-brained scheme SG-1 was cooking up. He was willing to let his officers' discipline slide a little.
- He was on his way to retirement. Who cares about busting some Privates' chops for fooling around on duty when you know you're going to retire in a couple of months?
- He was effectively holding keep of a backwater, non-priority station. An "alien device/military application" experiment that was shut-down. His personnel were being shipped away to more high-priority tasks, leaving him with a skeleton crew of personnel (who probably weren't the greatest officers to begin with, otherwise they'd also be shipped off) He knew how quickly boredom set in, and just turned a blind eye to whatever they were doing.

So, from the officer's perspective of "No-one ever comes down here" He just assumed that Hammond didn't know, or didn't care.

Comment: Hm... maybe I'm missing something, but this seems to be answering a different question than what was asked. I thought the question was asking why the soldier would say "nobody [else] ever comes down here" despite the fact that there _is_ at least one other person down there - namely General Hammond, in his office - and presumably many other personnel too, given that the general has an office on site. But this answer seems to be about why the soldiers wouldn't worry about getting caught. Of course, it's accepted, so clearly it was good enough for the OP, it just seems incongruous to me.

Comment: @DavidZ - I interpreted it as 'Noone ever comes down to [The Gate Room]', and with Hammond's office being two floors up (First up into the Dialing room, then up the spiral staircase into the board room/Hammond's office), that statement from the Officer could well hold true. What reason would Hammond have to go down further than his office? Having said that, that wouldn't explain why he chose to ignore what sounds suspiciously like a Poker game echoing in the Gate room, which was the focal point of my answer :).

Answer (score 0):

I interpreted it as no one visited the gate room.